# jQuery : Why removing draggable's parent breaks draggables?

Tags: jquery, draggable

I came across this problem trying to improve performance on manipulating huge lists of draggables; I tried removing a parent container so batch processing items would get faster (so each processing would not fire a DOM refresh) and re-inserting the container afterwards did cause the draggables to stop working. For example

```
<div id="listParent">
<div id="listWrapper">
    <ul id="draggableList">
       <li class="draggable">Item 1</li>
       <li class="draggable">Item 2</li>
       <li class="draggable">Item 3</li>
       <li class="draggable">Item 4</li>
       <li class="draggable">Item 5</li>
       <!-- many more items here -->
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
      revert: true
   });

   function filterItems(text) {
      var p = $('#listWrapper').remove();

      // for each <LI> element, hide the ones who do not match `text`'s value

      p.appendTo('#listParent');
   }
   // ...
});
</script>
```

So, invoking `filterItems('foo');`, for example, cause the items to not be draggables anymore. Do I have to re-apply draggable on the `<LI>` elements again? If so, then there is no point of removing the parent to speed up the process if I have to re-apply something afterward anyway, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.detach()` instead of `.remove()` to preserve attached event handlers. Here's an excerpt from the docs.

> .remove() method takes elements out of the DOM. Use .remove() when you
>   want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In
>   addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data
>   associated with the elements are removed. **To remove the elements
>   without removing data and events, use .detach() instead.**

Emphasis mine.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ypd9d/2/).

Comment: ah! yes! I've never really had to use that method before. Thanks!